# jqx validator not working properly

Tags: jquery, validation, action, jqxwidgets

jqx validator required two clicks in order to remove the validation message even if input box is not empty.

I have used bootstrap timepicker for the input box

```
<input id="eventDate" type="text"  type="text" class="datepicker"  placeholder="Event Date" />
```

The jqx validation code is

```
{ input: '#eventDate', message: 'Event Date required!', action: 'click, blur', rule: 'required' },
{ input: '#startTime', message: 'Starttime is required!', action: 'keyup, blur', rule: 'required' },
{ input: '#endDate', message: 'EventEndDate is required!', action: 'keyup, blur', rule: 'required' },
```

can anyone suggest action for the validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find the appropriate solution for the problem.that is the correct action required.But i have solved it by using some other way.

```
$('#test').jqxValidator('hide');
```

test is my div that contains the jqxvalidator. so on action of input box the above function is called.